# How to convert values to array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Suppose I have this data:

```
var id = 81;
var categories = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

How do I transform this into:

```
[{id: 81, category: 1}, {id: 81, category: 2}, {id: 81, category: 3}, {id: 81, category: 4}, {id: 81, category: 5}]
```

Is there an elegant way to do this using underscore or lodash?

Answer (score 9):

No need for libraries here.

```
const result = categories.map(x => ({ id, category: x }))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Working Example JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kabamu/3/edit?js,console)

```
var id = 81;
var categories = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
  arr.push({id: id, category: categories[i]});
}
```

Or:

```
var a = categories.map(function(a) {
  return {id: id, category: a};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any library, just good, old Vanilla JS.

```
var newArray = categories.map(function(item) {
  return {id: id, cetegory: item}
});
```

Comment: The irony: Vanilla.js is a library, a *0 byte library*.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lo-Dash/Underscore, the code would be:

```
var result = _.map(categories, x => ({ id, category: x }));
```

But this is actually longer than the pure JS solution ([from Роман Парадеев](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36829617/5743988)):

```
var result = categories.map(x => ({ id, category: x }));
```